# jquery не работают ссылки после подсветки div'a

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте, такая проблема, хочу просто подсветить выбранный пункт меню по щелчку, чтобы пользователь видел в каком разделе он находиться, подсветка с помощью jquery работает, но теперь ссылки ведущие на разные категории не работают: код ниже. Сниппет вставил ниже, вставил саму фотку что блок подсвечивается, но ссылки не работают, помогите исправить скрипт пожалуйста.  Делаю всё на .Net Mvc

```js
var classHighlight = 'highlight';

var $thumbs = $('.menu_block').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


  $thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
  //add the class to the currently clicked element (this)
  $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  div.menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .list_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  div.menu_block {
    width: 146px;
    height: 66px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-right-color: #562E07;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .highlight {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  div.menu_block:hover {
    background-color: #d19e6a;
    opacity: .8;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  div.menu_block:hover img {} .list_menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 146px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .list_menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
    z-index: 10;
    /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
    background-color: none;
    color: black;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  }
  .list_menu li a img {
    width: 37px;
    height: 33px;
  }
  .list_menu img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #926E49;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 430px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .list_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .menu_block {} .list_menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 14%;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .list_menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
    z-index: 10;
    /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
    background-color: white;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  }
  .list_menu li img {
    width: 37px;
    height: 33px;
  }
  .list_menu img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #926E49;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 429px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
  }
  .list_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .list_menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
    z-index: 10;
    /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
    background-color: white;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  }
  .menu_block {} .list_menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .list_menu li a img {
    width: 37px;
    height: 33px;
    display: none;
  }
  br {
    display: none;
  }
  .hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #926E49;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list_menu">

    <li>

      <a class="test" href="/Furniture/List">
        <div class="menu_block">
          <img src="~/Content/img/img0008.png" alt="">
          <br>Всі</div>
      </a>
    </li>


    <li>
      <a href="/Furniture/List?category=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8&amp;page=1">
        <div class="menu_block">
          <img src="~/Content/img/img0009.png" alt="">
          <br>Комоди</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Картника меню]

Comment: Вот эта строчка e.preventDefault(); отменяет переход по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var classHighlight = 'highlight';

$('li').click(function(e) {
  $('li').removeClass(classHighlight);
  //add the class to the currently clicked element (this)
  $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
});
```

```css
li {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: cyan;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  div.menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .list_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  div.menu_block {
    width: 146px;
    height: 66px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-right-color: #562E07;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .highlight {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
  div.menu_block:hover {
    background-color: #d19e6a;
    opacity: .8;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  div.menu_block:hover img {} .list_menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 146px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  .list_menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
    z-index: 10;
    /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
    background-color: none;
    color: black;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  }
  .list_menu li a img {
    width: 37px;
    height: 33px;
  }
  .list_menu img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #926E49;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 430px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
  }
  .list_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .menu_block {} .list_menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 14%;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .list_menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
    z-index: 10;
    /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
    background-color: white;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  }
  .list_menu li img {
    width: 37px;
    height: 33px;
  }
  .list_menu img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #926E49;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 429px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
  }
  .list_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .list_menu li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Makes sure the link doesn't get underlined */
    z-index: 10;
    /* raises anchor tag above everything else in div */
    background-color: white;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    opacity: 0;
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    /*workaround to make clickable in IE */
  }
  .menu_block {} .list_menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .list_menu li a img {
    width: 37px;
    height: 33px;
    display: none;
  }
  br {
    display: none;
  }
  .hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #926E49;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list_menu">

    <li>

      <a class="test" href="#">
        <div class="menu_block">
          <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2014/1/633/w512h5121390857008food512.png" alt="">
          <br>Все</div>
      </a>
    </li>


    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menu_block">
          <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Android/PNG/512/Household/kitchen-512.png" alt="">
          <br>Комоды</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо вам конечно , но у меня какой то прикол что как только кликаешь то цвет появляется и сразу пропадает, у меня подозрение на то что мешает div.list_menu:hover , я просто сделал чтобы по наводке мышки оно тоже светилось, не могли бы вы посмотреть

Comment: По сути оно подсвечивает только когда 2 раза кликаешь на блок :/

Comment: @M-Misha-M все исчезает, потомучто линк срабатывает...

Comment: @M-Misha-M сделал чтобы не пропадало...

Comment: извините не понимаю что меняется , у меня по прежнему пропадает, какой параметр за это отвечает?  Просто мне нужно чтобы после клика сохранялось состояние подсветки

Comment: @M-Misha-M так, я запутался... какого эффекта вы ожидаете?

Comment: смотрите перейдите пожалуйста на этот сайт https://www.taburetka.ua/ и кликните вверху на блок меню, видите когда вы кликнули на меню оно перешло в категорию и эффект подсветки остался. мне нужно так же, чтобы мы перешли в категорию и подсветка категории после клика осталась

Comment: @M-Misha-M так там каждый раз новый html строиться.....

Comment: у меня почти так же , у меня меню на всех страницах будет отображаться, вот похожий вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css задавали здесь, но я немного не понимаю как данный решение применить к моему коду

Comment: @M-Misha-M ну так и решение есть. вы на каждой странице своей категории меню(страница которого открыта) присваиваете класс (к примеру: "active")  . а в css задайте цвет этому классу.

Comment: вообщем я что то такое намутил, брал код отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646775/active-menu-highlight-css где сам топик стартер ответил и вот что получилось  http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1483124608/02a7520c/15503378.png . оно отображает теперь по дефолту желтый а не при клике

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50963/discussion-between-c-raf-t-and-m-misha-m).